# Flutter|How to change the colour of the button inside AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, dart

everyone!
I'm begging for help.
I have a StatefulWidget in which I call AlertDialog, created initState and setState, but button colour changes only if I close and reopen AlertDialog, not immediately when clicked.
I need to figure out how to redraw this window or some other way.
There's another problem, if I put the FloatingActionButton in a separate file and therefore in a separate StatefulWidget, the list itself doesn't update when I click Add, but if I put the FloatingActionButton back in the homepage, everything works. But that's an additional question) A big request for help with the ElevatedButton "Work" inside the AlertDialog.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late String _addField;
  late IconData _selectedValue;
  late bool _active;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _addField = 'Pusto';
    _active = false;
    _selectedValue = Icons.delete_forever_outlined;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
          child: Column(children: [
            ActiveTaskInfo(
              task: tasks.first,
            ),
            const TextWidget(),
            Expanded(child: TasksList()),
          ]),
        ),
        //bottomNavigationBar: const BottomBar(),
        //floatingActionButton: FloatingButton(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: const Text('Add Task'),
                    content: TextField(onChanged: (String value) {
                      _addField = value;
                    }),
                    actions: [
                      DropdownButton<IconData>(
                        value: _selectedValue,
                        onChanged: (IconData? newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedValue = newValue!;
                          });
                        },
                        items: dropdownItems,
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              tasks.addAll({
                                TaskData(
                                    taskName: _addField,
                                    tagNameOne: 'Work',
                                    tagNameTwo: 'Rasion Project',
                                    icon: _selectedValue,
                                    taskTime: '00:32:10')
                              });
                              decorations.addAll({
                                TaskTagsDecorations(
                                    firstTagTextColor: const Color(0xffFD5B71),
                                    secondTagTextColor: const Color(0xff9B51E0),
                                    firstTagColor: const Color(0xff1F0D20),
                                    secondTagColor: const Color(0xff150C2B),
                                    iconColor: const Color(0xff7012CF))
                              });
                            });
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: const Text('Add')),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _active = !_active;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text('Work'),
                       style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all(_active ? Colors.blue : Colors.red)
                          ),
                        ),
                    ],
                  );
                });
          },
          child: const Text('Add'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the widget you want to change inside **StatefulBuilder** in your case Elevated Button

```
StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, myState) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        myState(() {
          _active = !_active;
        });
      },
      child: Text('Work'),
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              _active ? Colors.blue : Colors.red)),
    );
  }),
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current `setState` is only working for `HomeScreen` context. You need to separate the dialog as a `stateful widget` to make `setState` working on the dialog.

Here a working example for it (Try to run it in [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/)):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Home Page")),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Home Page Content')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => const MyAlertDialog(),
          );
        },
        tooltip: 'Dialog',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAlertDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAlertDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyAlertDialog> createState() => _MyAlertDialogState();
}

class _MyAlertDialogState extends State<MyAlertDialog> {
  bool _isChanged = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text("Dialog"),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: const [Text("Dialog content")],
      ),
      actions: [
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: _isChanged ? Colors.blue : Colors.green,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() => _isChanged = !_isChanged);
          },
          child: const Text("Change color"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I get the idea, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The dialog box does not update itself using set state. So you have to use other state managements like GetX or Provider to change the state of the widget. Secondly it will also help update the value you want to update using the button.